# Inserting a bullet-like symbol into a Textfield

Tags: java, user-interface, symbols

How do I insert a "dot" into a textField (part of a GUI) in Java? My code is for a loginFrame and what I want to do is change each char inserted into the password field immediately into a dot (just as if you are signing into your email). Whenever I copy and paste the symbol from word, it becomes an empty box because it is treated as an illegal symbol. I've looked around, but I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar question.
Thanks!!

Comment: What is a "textField"? What GUI library? Do you mean a Swing JTextField? Can you show what you've tried including code and pictures? Please give all the pertinent information in your question from the get go. Otherwise we have to guess, and there's a good chance we'll guess wrong.

Comment: If using Swing, use a JPasswordField, which will do that for you. If using another framework, say what it is. But I'm pretty sure it has the equivalent.

Comment: If you want to use unusual symbols that you can't find on your keyboard, you could consider unicode. The bullet unicode is U+2022, so using textField.setText( "\u2022" ); might work for you. Of course, if you're doing passwords, you'll probably want to use JPasswordField.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `JPasswordField` instead. It works exactly the same as `JTextField`, except it automatically replaces all typed text with a look-and-feel dependent character, and you should use the `getPassword` method to retrieve the password instead of `getText`.